# psql: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "xxx" with method trust

Tags: postgresql, centos6

I've created a new role and Database in the following way (with postgres user):

```
CREATE ROLE xxx LOGIN
  PASSWORD 'CHOOSEAPASSWORD'
  NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION;

CREATE DATABASE xxx
  WITH OWNER = xxx
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

\connect xxx
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE xxx TO xxx;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO xxx;
```

In the pg_hba.conf I've the following entries:

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             xxx             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
```

Nevertheless I can't connect with

```
psql -U xxx -h localhost -W
```

and get the error

```
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "xxx"
```

Any ideas where I could have a mistake? (I use PostgreSQL 9.4 and CentOS 6.7)

Comment: Are there other `pg_hba.conf` entries above? Did you `pg_ctl reload` or `select pg_reload_conf()` after making the change?

Comment: There are no other entries in pg_hba.conf (behind is another entry for IPv6). I used the init script to restart after making the changes. (So I'm using neither pg_ctl reload nor select pg_reload_conf())

Comment: ... and if you use `-h 127.0.0.1` instead of `-h localhost`?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 works! But why? Technically 127.0.0.1 = localhost...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined a rule for IPv6's localhost address `::1`. Your host's resolver prefers the IPv6 address `::1` to the IPv4 address `127.0.0.1`. So the IPv4 rule with `trust` never gets matched.

Add another rule for `::1`

Another common issue, though already ruled out for you, is not having reloaded the config.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use **127.0.0.1** instead of **localhost**

Comment: Can you explailn why it work on 127.0.0.1 but not on localhost?